# Can't find GIMP 2.10 folder in 16.04

Tags: gimp

I recently deleted GIMP 2.8 and installed 2.10, the version maintained by Snapcrafters for pre-18.04. I'm trying to use a new font with GIMP and can't find the program folder anywhere (installing the font globally isn't reflected in GIMP). I've looked through the home folder as well as `~/.local/share` and it doesn't seem to be anywhere. How can I find GIMP's filepath?

Comment: Snaps are generally installed in /var/lib/snapd/snaps.  They are not expanded (ie. squashfs).  A snaps confinement level will control if they can/cannot access files outside of the snap itself (https://docs.snapcraft.io/snap-confinement/6233)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Two ways:

1. **Edit** > **Preferences** > **Folders** > **Fonts**: two folders, at least one should be under your `/home`.
2. **Filters** > **Python-fu** > **Console** and enter `print gimp.directory`. Your `fonts` directory is a child of that directory

Comment: The second option didn't work for me (also it's called `Script-fu`), the Python console said `#<CLOSURE>Error: eval: unbound variable: gimp.directory`. And the first one didn't really want to output the actual directory's location :/

Comment: @nyov No, the second option is really `python-fu`. But on recent Ubuntu you need to have the Python support in Gimp explicitly installed (`apt install gimp-python`)(without python support some plugins don't work and won't even show up in the menus).

Comment: thanks, that helped. Sorry, my mistake (perhaps add it to the answer).

Answer (score 3):

Missing the `~/.gimp-2.10` directory, when you know it should be there based on the `~/.gimp-2.4/`, `~/.gimp-2.6/` and `~/.gimp-2.8/` folders still lying around there?

In short, it's now in: `~/.config/GIMP/2.10/`.

(*sigh*. Finally, that clutter leaves my $HOME. Hurray for that.)

Comment: it's not there.

Answer (score 1):

In case you used flatpak to install, the path is:

```
~/.var/app/org.gimp.GIMP/config/GIMP/2.10
```